# Problem when accessing an object (UIView) with another class object!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have two classes A and B.

Class A contains a UIView named myView and also a method MyMethod to set the position of the myView.

```
-(void)MyMethod:(NSString *)justCheck
{   
[self.view addSubview:myView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myView];

CGRect mframe = [myView frame];

NSLog(@"------------> MyMethod Called = %@",justCheck); 


  // EDIT: the following NSLogs are added later--------------------

NSLog(@"------------> MyMethod Called:mframe:x = %g",mframe.origin.x);      //0

NSLog(@"------------> MyMethod Called:mframe:y = %g",mframe.origin.y);      //42

NSLog(@"------------> MyMethod Called:mframe:H = %g",mframe.size.height);   //317

NSLog(@"------------> MyMethod Called:mframe:W = %g",mframe.size.width);    //320


  //---------------------------------------------------------------

mframe.origin.y = 42; 

[myView setFrame:mframe];
}
```

When a button in the class A named buttonOfA calls this MyMethod, it works perfectly and I can see the myView in position 42.
code is as below,

```
-(IBAction)buttonOfA:(id)sender 
{
[self MyMethod:@"I am A"];
}
```

But, when the button of class B named buttonOfB tries to call this method, NSLog works but I cannot see the myView in position 42. Code as below,

```
  -(IBAction)buttonOfB:(id)sender 
{
[objOfA MyMethod:@"I am B"];  //objOfA is the object of class A
}
```

**What is happening here??**
I have been trying hard to figure out the problem, But I couldn't. Plz help me.

Thanx :)

**EDIT: four NSLogs are added in myMethod()**

Comment: Sounds like objOfA is nil. How do you set it?

Comment: @hwaxxer - Its like   A *objOfA = [[A alloc] init];   And note that, The NSLog message is printed to the console as ------------> MyMethod Called = I am B . If objOfA wal nil, could it be printed?

Comment: Yes you're right. Missed that NSLog worked fine. Perhaps the view is nil at the time of the call.

Comment: @hwaxxer - I edited the question. I could get the x, y, Height and width of the mframe, but cannot see the view. I think myView is being shown but some way it is not visible. What it could be? any idea?

Comment: It's probably just not added to a superview. Where and how do you add myView to A's view?

Comment: @hwaxxer - plz check my edited code. just now edited question. I added myView before the code CGRect mframe = [myView frame]; But still have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `myView` instance variable in the class A object is initialized and added to a super view when class B calls `MyMethod:` on it. Otherwise setting the frame won't have any effect.

Comment: I edited the question. I could get the x, y, Height and width of the mframe, but cannot see the view. I think myView is being shown but some way it is not visible. What it could be? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hold a reference to the object of type A, but it should be the same object which created the UIView. Hence it is better to return the singleton instance of the object.

Using the returned singleton for the Class A object call your method.

Comment: myMethod is in Class A and I am trying to call from Class B. Then how can use self?

Comment: Thanx for the answer :) I am a beginner and Could you plz simplify the answer with some example.

Comment: I edited the question. I could get the x, y, Height and width of the mframe, but cannot see the view. I think myView is being shown but some way it is not visible. What it could be? any idea?

Comment: Can you post the code from wehre you are getting the object of class A?

Answer (score -1):

because myView is not a property just make it property of class A and do this work

```
-(void)MyMethod:(NSString *)justCheck
{   

    CGRect mframe = [self.myView frame];

    NSLog(@"------------> MyMethod Called = %@",justCheck); 

    mframe.origin.y = 42; 

    [self.myView setFrame:mframe];
}
```

To make it a property instead of declaring it as
    UIView* myView;

Do it as like this in `.h` file

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView* myView;
```

and in `.m` of class `A` do it like this

```
@synthesize myView;
```

and you don't have to change anything in code just replace all `myView` with `self.myView`

Comment: There's no code to prove this. See my comment on the original question.

Comment: ya there is because he is getting the output form NSLog see the 5th line from below